# SQL date error code 1292

Tags: mysql, sql

When running this query:

```
INSERT INTO `user_events` (`id`, `name`, `date`, `type_id`, `user_id`)
 VALUES (64,'Wed','2017-03-11',17,54);
```

I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '000.00.00' for column 'date'
>   at row 1

It seems all similar questions resulted from using a date format other than `YYYY-MM-DD`, but I am using that format and still get this error. Is there something I need to change? (note that column `date` is of type date).

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table?

Comment: [tag:mysql]? If so, please [edit] and add that tag. If not, please edit and add the *appropriate* tag for your database system.

Comment: @GarethLyons there was. That was the issue.